# LightBox working locally from file:open, but not from local webserver or hosted webserver

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I have the follow code that works when I open it directly from desktop to browser. But when I open it up from localhost, or actual webserver and it does not work. Any help is appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>damnthing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" /> 
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'        : 'none',
        'transitionOut'        : 'none',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg" />
    </a>

    <a rel="example_group" title="Title of video here" class="various iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/24081323?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">
        <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91_m.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure it is something that I am overlooking as I am still learning the whole css/jquery/lightbox thing. Also

Comment: You may not be allowed to call resources from another domain `http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js` ... you may need to host the resources in your own server and call them from there or use CDN servers like `//yandex.st/jquery/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox.min.js`

Comment: That did it! I changed all the script paths to local ones and made sure I wasn't using a mixture of LB 1 & 2!